# Distribute volume (demands) equally cross the weekdays with Pulp

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I have to schedule stores across the weekdays, but of course, there is a capacity for one route and the stores have a different number of days drops.

To be more clarified there is a truck that will be moved on a daily basis, but for stores, some of them should be dropped on all 6 days, some of them only two days, and so on.

**Key** represents the store name and **value** represents the number of days

```py
Days = {
    "S1":6, "S2":6, "S3":6, "S4":3, "S5":3,
    "S6":3, "S7":2, "S8":2, "S9":2, "S10":1,
    "S11":1, "S12":1, "S13":1 ,"S13":1,
    "S14":1, "S15":1 
}
```

The demands (Volume) is the total of cartons for all six days for each store.

I tried to divide the demand by the number of days to find the approximate number of cartons per day. I am not sure if it is a good approach.

```py
Demand = {
    "S1":400/6, "S2":300/6, "S3":250/6, "S4":200/3, "S5":300/3,
    "S6":200/3, "S7":300/2, "S8":200/2, "S9":300/2, "S10":50/1,
    "S11":40/1, "S12":45/1, "S13":30/1, "S13":44/1, "S14":47/1,
    "S15":60/1,
}
```

The capacity is a total of carton for all stores, I divided the demand by the available six days as I did with store demands

```py
Capacity = 2736/6
```

I wanted to distribute the stores evenly across the weekdays based on their volumes, so I used this constraint to achieve it:

```py
for d in no_days_list:
    prob += pulp.lpSum([Demand[s] * storeVars[d][s] for s in Store]) <= Capacity
```

Unfortunately, there are two problems with this constraint:

- if the store demands after dividing them by the number of days are greater than the capacity I will get a non-optimal solution (-1) - (I am looking for a flexible constraint that accepts any volume if it approximately equals to capacity)
- if the store demands are much less than the capacity, I will get an optimal solution (1)
  but it will not be distributed evenly some of the days have volume and number of stores that are greater than others - (I guess I have to add one more constraint to solve this case to distribute them evenly as much as possible)

It is Ok for me If I removed this constraint if I found a solution for the second point.

Please, I need your suggestions to enhance the code.

```py
StoreSched = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Store_Code","Route","Demand"])
Capacity = 2736/6

route="R1"
days_list=["SAT","SUN","MON", "TUE","WED","THU"]
no_days_list = range(1,7)
Store = ["S1","S2","S3","S4","S5","S6","S7","S8","S9","S10","S11","S12","S13","S14","S15"]
Demand = {
    "S1":400/6, "S2":300/6, "S3":250/6 ,   "S4":200/3 , "S5":300/3,     
    "S6":200/3 ,  "S7":300/2, "S8":200/2, "S9":300/2,  "S10":50/1, 
    "S11":40/1,  "S12":45/1, "S13":30/1, "S13":44/1,    "S14":47/1,
    "S15":60/1,
}

Days = {
    "S1":6, "S2":6, "S3":6 , "S4":3, "S5":3,
    "S6":3, "S7":2, "S8":2, "S9":2, "S10":1,
    "S11":1, "S12":1, "S13":1, "S13":1,
    "S14":1, "S15":1,
}
    
prob = LpProblem("store_schedule",LpMaximize)
storeVars = LpVariable.dicts("Days",(no_days_list,Store),0,1,LpInteger)
    
for d in no_days_list:
    prob += pulp.lpSum([Demand[s] * storeVars[d][s] for s in Store]) <= Capacity
for s in Store:
    # Every store should be assigned based on its DayNo.
    prob += pulp.lpSum(storeVars[d][s] for d in no_days_list) == Days[s]

prob.solve()
print(prob.solve())
for vi in prob.variables():
    if vi.varValue == 1:
        code= vi.name.split("_")[2];
        day = days_list[int(vi.name.split("_")[1])-1];
        if ((StoreSched['Store_Code'] == code).any() == False):
            StoreSched = StoreSched.append({'Store_Code': code,"Route":route,"Days":Days[code],"Demand":Demand[code]}, ignore_index=True)
        for index in StoreSched.index:    
            if StoreSched.loc[index,'Store_Code']== code:                    
                StoreSched.loc[index,day] = 1                    
StoreSched.fillna(0,inplace=True)
StoreSched
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to minimize the difference between the maximum load on a day and the minimum load on a day. Change to a `LpMinimize`-problem:

```
prob = LpProblem("store_schedule",LpMinimize)
```

Introduce two variables `minLoad` and `maxLoad`:

```
minLoad = LpVariable("minLoad", 0, Capacity, cat=LpContinuous)
maxLoad = LpVariable("maxLoad", 0, Capacity, cat=LpContinuous)
```

Add as objective:

```
prob += maxLoad - minLoad
```

Add constraints to set the new variables:

```
for d in no_days_list:
    prob += minLoad <= pulp.lpSum([Demand[s] * storeVars[d][s] for s in Store])
    prob += maxLoad >= pulp.lpSum([Demand[s] * storeVars[d][s] for s in Store])
```

To make the problem feasible you would need to increase the `Capacity`, i.e. like:

```
Capacity = 2836/6
```

Runtime with the CBC MILP Solver is quite bad. You could improve by additional constraints on `storeVars`:

```
for s in Store:
    if Days[s] == 2:
        for d in range(1,5):
            prob += pulp.lpSum(storeVars[d][s] + storeVars[d+1][s] + storeVars[d+2][s]) <= 1
    if Days[s] == 3:
        for d in range(1,6):
            prob += pulp.lpSum(storeVars[d][s] + storeVars[d+1][s]) <= 1
```

Running give a load per day:

```
d = 1, load = 465.0
d = 2, load = 464.0
d = 3, load = 455.33333333333337
d = 4, load = 458.33333333333337
d = 5, load = 441.6666666666667
d = 6, load = 451.6666666666667
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried your solution it is working perfectly and this what I needed, unfortunately, this works with dummy data. I have actually about 900 stores and 20 routes. so the runtime is very slow and I can not get any result for more than an hour. I looked up about this problem I found some people recommended  LpAffineExpression class. what do you think

Comment: I don't think you will be able to solve this model with that data using the CBC solver. If possible, you could try with a commercial solver like CPLEX. Another idea would be to simplify the problem by grouping the stores in advance (and solve using groups of stores instead of stores) or considering a meta-heuristic based approach like local search.